# How to add the return value to the cth_surefire XML report?

Tags: xml, erlang, erlang-otp, common-test

I am using erlangOTP and the [common test framework](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/).

The XML test reort is produced by using the [common test hook](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/ct_hooks_chapter.html) `cth_surefire`.

Every test case ends by returning a customized stringsomehow like this:

```
Comment = io_lib:format( "Success with blah blah. foo: ~w ~n", [foo]),
Result = { comment, Comment }
.
```

Nevertheless the XML report does not include the `Result` mentioned above.

**How to add the `Result` value to the cth_surefire XML report?**